# Select paragraph based on text content

Tags: css

Trying to use the `[attribute$=value]` selector (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp) to change the color of a p text.  I'm trying to select the last `<p>` tag that ends with "concerns."  I tried using `[p*="concern]` but it didn't work, so I tried using referring to it by its adjacent sibling `.resident_btn`  code: `.resident_btn + [p* = "concern"]` but that didn't work either.  I'm not sure how to get it to work.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="holder">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <p>Pay your rent or schedule automatic payments quickly and securely.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <p>Have an issue in your apartment? Complete a request for maintenance and a member of our team will service your apartment as quickly as possible. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <a class="resident_btn" href="resident-contact-request.asp"></a>
   <p>How can we help? Contact the leasing team with any questions or concerns.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't select elements based on their **content**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **CSS only** the only way I can think of is that you:

- **apply the same content string into a `data-*` attribute** (in this case `data-content`)
- Target the element using **attribute selector** `[data-content$="concerns."]`

```css
[data-content$="concerns."]{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<p data-content="Pay quickly and securely.">Pay quickly and securely.</p>
<p data-content="Request for maintenance.">Request for maintenance.</p>
<p data-content="Any questions or concerns.">Any questions or concerns.</p>
```

Here's an example using **only** the data-* attribute (no actual HTML content)

```css
[data-content]:before{
    content: attr(data-content);
}
[data-content$="concerns."]{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<p data-content="Pay quickly and securely."></p>
<p data-content="Request for maintenance."></p>
<p data-content="Any questions or concerns."></p>
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks!  I had to read up on data attributes to fully understand how they work.  If anyone else needs a refresher here's a link explaining data attributes: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642